# One of the numbers $\zeta(5), \zeta(7), \zeta(9), \zeta(11)$ is irrational

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, riemann-zeta-function, computational-number-theory, transcendental-number-theory

I am reading an interesting paper [One of the numbers ζ(5), ζ(7), ζ(9), ζ(11) is irrational](https://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=rm&paperid=427&option_lang=eng) by Zudilin. We fix odd numbers $q$ and $r$, $q\geq r+4$ and a tuple $\eta_0,\eta_1,...,\eta_q$ of positive integer parameters satisfying the conditions $\eta_1\leq \eta_2\leq...\leq \eta_q<\eta_0/2$ and $$ \eta_1+\eta_2+...+\eta_q\leq \eta_0\left(\frac{q-r}{2}\right)\tag{1}$$
Define $$F_n:=\frac{1}{(r-1)!}\sum_{t=0}^\infty R_n^{(r-1)}(t)\tag{2}$$ and note that $R_n(t)=O(t^{-2})$. We put $m_j=\max\{\eta_r,\eta_0-2\eta_{r+1},\eta_0-\eta_1-\eta_{r+j}\}$ for $j=1,2,...,q-r$ and define the integer $$\Phi_n:=\prod_{\sqrt{\eta_0 n}<p\leq m_{q-r}n}p^{\varphi(n/p)}$$ where only primes enter the product and $$\varphi(x)=\min_{0\leq y<1}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{r}([y]+[\eta_0x-y]-[y-\eta_j x]-[(\eta_0-\eta_j)x-y]-2[\eta_j x])+\sum_{j=r+1}^{q}([(\eta_0-2\eta_j)x]-[y-\eta_j x]-[(\eta_0-\eta_j)x-y])\right)$$ where [.] denotes the ceiling function. Let $D_N$ denote the lcm of $1,2,...,N$.

**Lemma $1$:** ($2$) defines a linear form of $\zeta(r+2),\zeta(r+4),...,\zeta(q-2)$ with rational coefficients; moreover, $$ D_{m_1n}^r D_{m_2n... D_{m_{q-r}n}}.\Phi_n^{-1}.F_n\in\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\zeta(r+2)+\mathbb{Z}\zeta(r+4)+...+\mathbb{Z}\zeta(q-2) \tag{3}$$
By Prime Number Theorem, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log D_{m_j n}}{n}=m_j,\ \ \ j=1,...,q-r.$$
We introduce the auxiliary function $$f_0(\tau)=r\eta_0\log(\eta_0-\tau)+\sum_{j=1}^{q} (\eta_j\log(\tau-\eta_j)-(\eta_0-\eta_j)\log(\tau-\eta_0+\eta_j)) -2\sum_{j=1}^r \eta_j\log \eta_j+\sum_{j=r+1}^q (\eta_0-2\eta_j)\log(\eta_0-2\eta_j)$$ defined in the $\tau$-plane with the cuts $(-\infty,\eta_0-\eta_1]$ and $[\eta_0,+\infty)$

**Lemma $2$:** Let $r=3$ and $\tau_0$ be a zero of the polynomial $$(\tau-\eta_0)^r(\tau-\eta_1)...(\tau-\eta_q)-\tau^r(\tau-\eta_0+\eta_1)...(\tau-\eta_0+\eta_q) $$
with Im $\tau_0>0$ and the maximum possible value of Re $\tau_0$. Assume Re $\tau_0<\eta_0$ and Im $f_0(\tau_0)\notin \pi \mathbb{Z}.$
Then $$\overline{\lim}_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log |F_n|}{n}=Re f_0(\tau_0)$$ If the sequence of linear forms on the left side of ($3$) assumes non-zero arbitrarily small values as $n$ increases, then in the case $r=3$ there are irrational numbers among $$ \zeta(5),\zeta(7),...,\zeta(q-4),\zeta(q-2) \tag{4}$$ Therefore the following holds:

**Lemma $3$:** Suppose that $r=3$ and in the above notation $C_0=-Re f_0(\tau_0)$, $$C_1=rm_1+m_2+...+m_{q-r}-\left(\int_0^1\varphi(x)d\psi(x)-\int_0^{1/m_{q-r}}\varphi(x)\frac{dx}{x^2}\right)$$ where $\psi(x)=\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}$ is the logarithmic derivative of the Gamma function. If $C_0>C_1$, then at least of the numbers ($4$) is irrational.
The line below Lemma $3$ reads: we put, $r=3,q=13$, $$\eta_0=91,\eta_1=\eta_2=\eta_3=27,\eta_4=29,\eta_5=30,\eta_6=31,...,\eta_{12}=37,\eta_{13}=38.$$ Then $$C_0=227.58019641...,C_1=226.24944266...$$

> **Question:** Is the above result true only for $r=3$ or for other odd values of $r\geq 5$ also? For example can we take $r=5,q=15$ and if
> with suitable choice of $\eta's$, we show that $C_0>C_1$, can we say at least one of the four numbers $$ \zeta(7),\zeta(9),\zeta(11),\zeta(13)$$ is irrational? Rephrasing my question, Is Proposition $5$ in [Arithmetic of linear forms involving odd zeta values](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0206176) true for $r=5$ and $q=15$?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

**Edit** Proposition 5 only discusses the case $r=3$ - this is the one for which the author
has an application in the paper.
I think, the general statement for odd $r\geq 5$ is possible but the correct choice of
$\tau_0$ depends on $\eta's$.

Comment: I have not read this paper, but regarding Question 1 probably the author had a good reason to assume $r=3$, and regarding Question 2 the constant $C_1$ is defined by a formula in Lemma 3, so you should tell us which part of the formula is unclear to you. I am sure the value of $C_1$ was found by numeric integration by the author, using the definition and mathematical software.

Comment: @GHfromMO Thanks. In computing $C_1$, I am having trouble in finding the two integrations involved in $C_1$.

Comment: Well, just feed the functions into Mathematica, and you should get the result. Of course you need to rewrite $\int_0^1\varphi(x)\,d\psi(x)$ by integration parts: it equals $[\varphi(x)\psi(x)]_0^1-\int_0^1\varphi'(x)\psi(x)\,dx$. BTW the author is a friendly guy, feel free to ask him by email. Regarding Question 1, the author published later that one of the eight numbers $\zeta(5),\zeta(7),\dotsc,\zeta(19)$ is irrational. So I doubt there is a simple way to deduce that one of $\zeta(7),\zeta(9),\zeta(11),\zeta(13)$ is irrational.

Comment: @GHfromMO Thanks a lot. Sorry, I am new to Mathematica. I would request you to write an answer giving the mathematica code for computation of $C_1$. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, learn Mathematica or SAGE. For calculating these integrals, 60 minutes of learning and programming should be enough.

Comment: You can also play with the following website (which is based on Mathematica but easier to use): https://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: @GHfromMO Thanks again. But how do we enter $\varphi(x)$ in Wolfram alpha? Its a function which takes different values on different intervals.

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha is likely not strong enough for that purpose. It's *much* better to become familiar with SageMath.

Comment: @AlonAmit Thanks. Can you please give a SageMath code to calculate $C_1$?

Comment: With all this effort you could have contacted the author already (who is a person like us responding here). BTW you can break up the integral into pieces according to the various subintervals in the definition of $\varphi(x)$. Further questions regarding Mathematica should be asked at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ Finally, ChatGPT can also write SAGE code for you. You tell ChatGPT in human language what you want, and you will get SAGE code: https://chat.openai.com/

Comment: @GHfromMO Thank you for your nice advice. I tried suing ChatGPT and since it was too long for a comment, I have written a code as an answer. However I am getting an error. Please help me out to resolve the error. Thank you.

Comment: Your questions are about programming rather than mathematics. There are sites discussing Python, SAGE, etc. issues. My best advice at this point is to contact Zudilin, and ask him how he calculated his integrals. I doubt anyone here will write or debug code for you.